# Filter data based on nested array item using lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have following data and unable to filter

```js
{
  "data": {
    "Viewer": {
      "CampaignGrids": {
        "edges": [
          {
            "node": {
              "Name": "mega campaign",
              "Start_Date": "08/31/2020",
              "End_Date": "09/15/2020",
              "Promoted_Titles": [
                {
                  "Primary_ISBN": "4314323211",
                  "Book": null
                },
                {
                  "Primary_ISBN": "94232344",
                  "Book": null
                },
                {
                  "Primary_ISBN": "221235345",
                  "Book": null
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            "node": {
              "Name": "InActiveBook Campaign",
              "Start_Date": "08/14/2019",
              "End_Date": "08/14/2019",
              "Promoted_Titles": [
                {
                  "Primary_ISBN": "9781504011815",
                  "Book": {
                    "Primary_ISBN": "9781504011815",
                    "Active": true
                  }
                },
                {
                  "Primary_ISBN": "9780795336874",
                  "Book": {
                    "Primary_ISBN": "9780795336874",
                    "Active": true
                  }
                },
                {
                  "Primary_ISBN": "9781453244517",
                  "Book": {
                    "Primary_ISBN": "9781453244517",
                    "Active": true
                  }
                },
                {
                  "Primary_ISBN": "9781781892527",
                  "Book": {
                    "Primary_ISBN": "9781781892527",
                    "Active": false
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I need to filter all the campaigns which contain Active : False book

So based on above data, i need to get back following

```js
{"node": {
              "Name": "InActiveBook Campaign",
              "Start_Date": "08/14/2019",
              "End_Date": "08/14/2019",
              "Promoted_Titles": [
                {
                  "Primary_ISBN": "9781504011815",
                  "Book": {
                    "Primary_ISBN": "9781504011815",
                    "Active": true
                  }
                },
                {
                  "Primary_ISBN": "9780795336874",
                  "Book": {
                    "Primary_ISBN": "9780795336874",
                    "Active": true
                  }
                },
                {
                  "Primary_ISBN": "9781453244517",
                  "Book": {
                    "Primary_ISBN": "9781453244517",
                    "Active": true
                  }
                },
                {
                  "Primary_ISBN": "9781781892527",
                  "Book": {
                    "Primary_ISBN": "9781781892527",
                    "Active": false
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
            }
```

Currently i am using lodash library filter options. I tried following but it returns me both the data instead of just one

```js
  let flaged = _.filter(campaigns, function(item) {
 return _.filter(item.Promoted_Titles, function(o) {
     return o.Book.Active = false; 
 })
  });      

  console.log('flagged campaign ', JSON.stringify(flaged) , '\n');
```

I also tried following

```js
let flaged = filter(campaigns, function(el) {
     el.Promoted_Titles = filter(el.Promoted_Titles, function(item) {
       console.log('item is ', item);      
       return 'Book.Active' == false
     })   
     return el;
   })
```

But in both scenario, i get both item instead of just one. Thanks in advance

Comment: So you wish to filter campaigns or books in a given campaign?  It looks like you have a campaigns array and a nested array of books, so are you trying to filter campaigns where there are no active books? or at least 1 active book?

Comment: I am trying to filter campaigns where there is atleast one Inactive book

Comment: `o.Book.Active = false` is an assignment, not an equality check, `'Book.Active' == false` is always `false`, and nesting two `_.filter()` calls will always cause the outer callback to return a truthy value (which is effectively a shallow copy of the outer array)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with Lodash by defining the structure of a match in a [callback object](https://lodash.com/docs/2.4.2#filter) like so:

```js
let d = {"data":{"Viewer":{"CampaignGrids":{"edges":[{"node":{"Name":"mega campaign","Start_Date":"08/31/2020","End_Date":"09/15/2020","Promoted_Titles":[{"Primary_ISBN":"4314323211","Book":null},{"Primary_ISBN":"94232344","Book":null},{"Primary_ISBN":"221235345","Book":null}]}},{"node":{"Name":"InActiveBook Campaign","Start_Date":"08/14/2019","End_Date":"08/14/2019","Promoted_Titles":[{"Primary_ISBN":"9781504011815","Book":{"Primary_ISBN":"9781504011815","Active":true}},{"Primary_ISBN":"9780795336874","Book":{"Primary_ISBN":"9780795336874","Active":true}},{"Primary_ISBN":"9781453244517","Book":{"Primary_ISBN":"9781453244517","Active":true}},{"Primary_ISBN":"9781781892527","Book":{"Primary_ISBN":"9781781892527","Active":false}}]}}]}}}}

let e = d.data.Viewer.CampaignGrids.edges;
let a = _.filter(e, { node: { Promoted_Titles: [{ Book: { Active: false } }] } });

console.log(a);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have an object key called edges which is your array of nodes.

```
const results = edges.filter( edge => {
  return edge.node.Promoted_Titles.filter( promotedTitles => promotedTitles.Book.Active === false).length > 0)
});
```

This will return a list of edges which contain at least 1 inactive book.

Edit: I just swapped it around to show a list of edges / campaigns where there is at least 1 inactive book per your comments.